# Trying to update the function in script tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, runtime, updating, script-tag

I am creating a debugger utility to help me out in debugging without the to follow cumbersome process of redeploying and going to all the way to the page to test it.
so I have created the below functions which are called by various buttons.

```
     function updateTestCode()
    {
        $("script[for='testing']").html('');
        alert('Adding function ' + $('#_testArea').val());
        $("script[for='testing']").append($('#_testArea').val());



    }

function checkCode()
{
    alert('Calling Function ');
    try{
        validateFields();
    }catch(err)
    {
        form.showDebugMsg("Error When Running Script " + err);
    }
}

function generateScriptCode()
{
    $('#_testArea').val($("script[for='testing']").html());
}
```

Now all I wanted to do is to allow me to update the value of the function below and use it without the need for redeployment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" for='testing'>
function validateFields()
{
    alert('Hello World');

}</script>
```

Now the problem is that Firefox is able to update the code (IE throws error) and retrieve it. But when I try to click and execute the script it still show result of the old function.

Any Ideas what I might be doing wrong???

Comment: Can you recreate the error on jsFiddle?

Comment: I didn't try it there...I was thinking if functions like eval() can help me replacing the older instance of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're using the same script tag and changing the inner text. You have to add a new script tag.

```
scriptContent = "... function ...";

// delete old tag
$("#testScript").remove();

// add a new one
$("<script id='testScript'/>").text(scriptContent).appendTo("head");
```

Also, you cannot use `append()` to add text to an element like you're doing on your `updateTestCode()` function. You have to use the `text()`.

```
// use text(), not append()
$("script[for='testing']").text($('#_testArea').val());
```

Here an working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/MtY3h/

Comment: I tried what you had added to jfiddle, if I update the script tag I wanted the updated script to run. I update your jFiddle code as below 

`$("[data-which]").click(function(){`
`var n = $(this).attr("data-which");`
`var scriptContent = 'function testMe(){alert(\'Hello World\')}';`
`// delete old tag`
`$("#testScript").remove();`
`// add a new one`
`$("<script id='testScript'/>").text(scriptContent).appendTo("head");`
`// call function`
`sayHello();`
`testMe();`
`});`

Comment: Here is the link to fiddle I had created --> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xajat007/cZWHp/)

Comment: @Rox, by the way my fiddle in answer run the updated script in case you haven't notice.